# how to redirect the page analyzing url typed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need a page that when I load it check out the link typed for example: 
`www.test.com/myphp.php=10` 
if it finds certain number it redirects to another link for example: 
found `www.test.com/myphp.php=10` redirects to news `www.test.com/news/10.php`.

How can I do this and what technology should I use?

Comment: I would recommed you use a routhing method. An example is https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your syntax for GET variables is a little off. I assume you mean starting URLs of `test.com/myphp.php?redirect=10` or something similar? Because `www.test.com/myphp.php=10` is bad syntax.

I'm assuming we're using GET variables as described above in my answer:

---

The simplest way to do this would be to just set the location header in PHP:

```
if(array_key_exists("redirect", $_GET)){
    #set header to redirect to new location
    header("Location: /news/" . $_GET["redirect"] . ".php");
    #don't let the page do anything else
    die();
}else{
    #do something if the GET variable doesn't exist
}
```

Note that this way introduces a few security vulnerabilities, so you might want to do something more advanced (such as `intval` the GET variable so that they can't inject a script into your variable, or just `addslashes()` to the GET variable value).

Comment: Thanks for helping me , you and the others helped me , now I can make a more dynamic site.

*My English is not very good , sorry grammatical errors*

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `$_GET` variable like so

http://www.test.com/myphp.php?p=10

and for your php you can do this.

```
header('Location: /news/' . $_GET['p'] . '.php');
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Url should be with a get parameter name.
http://www.test.com/myphp.php?news=10

```
if(isset($_GET['news']) && is_numeric($_GET['news'])) {
     $newsUrl = 'http://www.test.com/news/' . (int)$_GET['news'] . '.php';
     header('location: ' . $newsUrl);
     // or 
     // header('location: /news/' . (int)$_GET['news']);
     die;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Plain old javascript

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
```

If the url is www.test.com/myphp.php?id=10
Calling getQueryVariable("id") would return 10

Then you just reroute using

```
var number = getQueryVariable('id')
window.location = "www.test.com/news/"+number+".php";
```